# Black Hole Scattering of Low-Frequency Light

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering-cross-section

What is the far-field interference pattern for low-frequency (i.e., the wavelength is much larger than the Schwarzschild radius)
electromagnetic plane wave radiation about a point mass?  I envision a plot of "scattered power density" vs "deflection angle"
(for a given incoming EM frequency, incoming EM power density, and mass).  Since the incoming plane wave establishes an "E direction"
and a perpendicular "M direction", should this plot depend on which of these directions I use to set the deflection angle?

It seems that this must include the effects of General Relativity and Wave Mechanics, so there might not be any accepted theory
here...but it makes for a fair thought experiment.

Comment: Even QFT on a curved spacetime is accepted and solvable, but you don't have to go that far -- this is just solving the wave equation on a well-behaved manifold, so it's definitely doable.

Comment: I guess the electric and magnetic fields would then be interchangeable, so the answer to my second question is No.  This still leaves me curious about whether there is full rotational symmetry (i.e., for deflections measured in any "diagonal direction" mixing the E and M axes).